Identification of cohomology groups of the classifying space of a group and the group cohomology
I'm struggling to understand the following identification of groups. Let us consider a $G$-space $G\overset{\varphi}{\curvearrowright}M$ and let $\varphi^*$ the induced action over the cohomology groups $H^q(M;\mathbb Z)$. Let $BG$ be the classifying space of $G$. Then we have the identification
$$
   H^p(BG; H^q(M;\mathbb Z))
   \simeq
   H^p_{\textrm{group}}(G;H^q(M;\mathbb Z))
   \qquad
   \forall p,q,
$$
where $H^p_{\textrm{group}}(G;H^q(M;\mathbb Z))$ is the group cohomology w.r.t. the lifted action $\varphi^*$. Can you provide an explanation? If it would be possible also precise references to understand this case with coefficients $H^q(M;\mathbb Z)$.

The point is that chains on $EG$ is a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}G$-module, so it can be used to compute group cohomology. I'm sure you can fill in the rest of the details.
